# Custom jQuery Validate method for ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

How to create a custom method with ajax for jQuery Validate plugin?
I did try the next way, but the validator returns every time invalid.

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('customValidator', function (value, element) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/validator/',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: {field: value},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                return result.data.valid;
            }
        });
        //.fail(function() {
        //    return false;
        //});
    }, '');
```

**I really have to create a new method, can not use the remote.**

Comment: *"can not use the remote."* ~ **Why?**  The `remote` method can already do what you're requesting.  The real solution is to simply use `remote`... this is exactly what it was designed to do.

Comment: Why to reinvent the wheel ? https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine - supports ajax validation

Comment: Why can't you use the `remote`?

Comment: What *exactly* is being returned by `result.data.valid`?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can do with `.ajax()` you can't do with the `remote` method, because `remote` is just a wrapper for `.ajax()`, not much different than yours. `remote` takes exactly the same options as `.ajax()` because that's the jQuery method it's using internally. There is no point in creating a custom method for `.ajax()` in this case.

Your code...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('customValidator', function (value, element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/validator/',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {field: value},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            return result.data.valid;
        }
    });
    //.fail(function() {
    //    return false;
    //});
}, 'Invalid national id');
```

Using `remote`, it is exactly the same, except less options are needed because they are already the default.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        yourfield: {
            remote: {
                url: '/ajax/validator/',
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                // data: {field: value}, // not needed, field data is sent by default
                // dataType: 'json',   // not needed, already default
                // success: {}       // not needed, plugin handles response automatically
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        yourfield: {
            remote: 'Invalid national id'
        }
    }
});
```

**Documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/**